# Injecting into Ember views

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

In Ember you can inject objects into views using an initializer as follows (Ember-CLI syntax):

```
export default {
  name: 'sayHello',

  initialize: function(container, app) {
    var thing = function() {
      return 'Hello';
    };

    app.register('sayHello:main', sayHello, { instantiate: false });
    app.inject('view', 'sayHello', 'sayHello:main');
  }
};
```

This injects the method into all views including link-tos, inputs, list items in a collection view, etc. This seems like it would hinder the app's performance if the thing being injected was substantially sized. In many situations, you just want to inject something into a route-specific view or controller. What I mean by that is a view that Ember automatically associates with the current route.

**Question**: Is there a way to inject objects into just the route-specific views and not into the link-tos, inputs, etc, and does injecting the methods into all views noticeably inhibit the application's performance?

Answer (score 0):

The ember guide says:

> Injections can also be made on a specific factory by using its full
>   name:
>
> ```
> application.inject('route:index', 'logger', 'logger:main');
> ```
>
> -- http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

So the question is – which factory do you want to target.

I'm not sure if there is a factory that includes all user-defined views, but excludes all framework views. You should probably be able to target single views with `view:application`, etc.

An option may be to have a proxy view, which extends Ember.View, and from which you extend all your app views.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Unfortunately, that's not a scalable option when working with 40-50 routes.